# Why Terraform updates google_compute_instance_group_manager version name?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm seeing this log randomly when applying terraform config even though nothing changed in this module or template or anything at all:

```
# module.my_module_name.google_compute_instance_group_manager.main will be updated in-place
~ resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "main" {
      id                        = "projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroupManagers/my-instance-group"
      name                      = "my-instance-group"
      # (11 unchanged attributes hidden)



    ~ version {
        - name              = "0/2022-11-02 13:32:38.953868+00:00" -> null
          # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
      }
      # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
  }
```

Here's the config:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "main" {
  name               = "${var.pipeline_id}-group"
  base_instance_name = "${var.pipeline_id}-group"
  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.main.id
  }

  auto_healing_policies {
    health_check      = google_compute_health_check.main.id
    initial_delay_sec = 300
  }
}
```

I tried to set a static version name, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: It might be that something has changed between provider versions if you updated it recently. The docs say for example the `name` argument in the version block is required: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_group_manager#name. As far as I can tell, you don't have that in your code.

Comment: This is most likely due to a functionality gap in the provider's code for the resource when setting/reading parameters in the payload for the API endpoint interaction, and is benign. You can probably file an issue if you want though.

Comment: @MarkoE I tried setting a static name, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform has lifecycle property applied to all resources.

```
lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [
    version[0].name
  ]
}
```